# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

estoy empezando a desarrollar en React...y en el proceso em topécon este error. "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"
tengo mi archivo Badges.js endonde tengo la data y la llamo desde mi archivo BadgesList.js para organizarla...pero el mapeo me sale mal y no entiendo el probelma.

Archivo BadgesList.js

```js
import React from 'react'

import './styles/BadgesList.css';
class BadgesList extends React.Component{
   render(){
      return (
         <ul className="list-unstyled BadgesList">
            {this.props.badges.map((badge)=>{
               return(
                  <li key={badge.id} className="BadgesListItem">
                     <img src='' alt="" className="BadgesListItem__avatar"/>
                     <div>
                        <div><strong>{badge.firstName} {badge.lastName}</strong></div>
                        <div className="Twitter__name">
                           <span className="Twitter__logo"></span>@{badge.twitter}
                        </div>
                        <div>{badge.jobTitle}</div>
                     </div>
                  </li>
               )
            })}
         </ul>
      )
   }
}

export default BadgesList
```

Comment: Puedes hacerle algun console.log this.props.badges para saber que trae los props asumiendo que le estas pasando los props correctamente al componente

Answer (score 1):

Puedes validar que this.props.badges sea diferente de undefined de esta manera:

`this.props.badges && this.props.badges.map((badge)=>{`